# Trying to sum the values of two arrays and send it to a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I am a total newbie in programming.... I have added my code to JSfiddle. Help on why this code doesnt work will be greatly appreciated.  Here is the link:
The aim is to add the values of the inAmounts array and outAmounts array together and display the result in the div with id "total"

http://jsfiddle.net/soundCat/umbWX/1/\

```
inAmounts=[2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2];
outAmounts=[2, 3, 2, 3, 4];

function displayCurrentBalance() {
    var sumIn = (inAmounts.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0));
    var sumOut = (outAmounts.reduce(function (c, d) {
        return c + d;
    }, 0));

    var total = sumIn - sumOut;
    $("div#total").html("The current balance is " + total);

}
```

Comment: Yeah so? What are you trying to do, and what isn't working? How can anyone solve your problem if you don't tell us what that problem _is_?

Comment: Why are you using `Array.reduce`? Please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: jQuery objects use jQuery methods (`.html()`), DOM nodes have access to the DOM API (`.innerHTML`). Mixing them up doesn't work.

Comment: I am trying to add the values of the array inAmounts and subtract the values of the array outAmounts to give me a total.  Then I want that total to be displayed into the div with id="total"

Comment: thanks for your time. your answer was helpful but hasnt solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using $ (i.e jQuery) then add jQuery plugin to your code.

Solution is:

```
  $("div#total").html("The current balance is " + total);
```

If you are not using jQuery then follow this:

```
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML="The current balance is " + total;
```

So your whole code from top to end becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
  inAmounts=[2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2];
  outAmounts=[2, 3, 2, 3, 4];

  function displayCurrentBalance() {
  var sumIn = (inAmounts.reduce(function (a, b) {
     return a + b;
  }, 0));
  var sumOut = (outAmounts.reduce(function (c, d) {
    return c + d;
  }, 0));

  var total = sumIn - sumOut;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML="The total is "+total;

  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="total"></div> <b style="margin-top:10%" onClick="displayCurrentBalance()">
<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: changed innerHTML to .html but it still doesnt write it to the div